# DSE Cassandra SOLR Query with whitespaces

Tags: database, solr, cassandra, lucene, datastax

I have Cassandra table with below data:

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE solr_query='{"q":"address:*"}';

name  | address                      | age | solr_query
-------+------------------------------+-----+------------
 test3 |          road3 united states |  23 |       null
 test4 |              road 123 canada |  23 |       null
 test2 |        street2 united states |  22 |       null
 test1 | 123 california united states |  21 |       null
 test5 |      123 Texas united states |  23 |       null
```

with schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="TestSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieIntField" name="TrieIntField"/>
</types>
<fields>
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="name" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="address" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="age" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>name</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

the perfect match for the string with spaces work
    cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE solr_query='{"q":"address:\"123 california united states\""}';

```
 name  | address                      | age | solr_query
-------+------------------------------+-----+------------
 test1 | 123 california united states |  21 |       null
```

but if I want to search the string that startwith "123" (regex for string with space) it fails. (tried other `solr query: {"q":"address:\"123\"*"})`

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE solr_query='{"q":"address:\"123\""}';

 name | address | age | solr_query
------+---------+-----+------------

(0 rows)
```

is there a way to get regex done on the solr string field type with spaces?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what did you use to properly integrate Solr with Cassandra. Haven't been able to find a useful tutorial so far.

Comment: Did you get answer to this ? I'm also unable to search with a text which has space in it

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE solr_query='{"q":"address:123*"}';` You remove the quotes as you no longer need the exact match.

Comment: Question is, if we need to search a something like (123 california united states)  what you are telling is using wildcard, it will give numerous results